# Valditity of upcasting members to single-property classes

Tags: c++, casting

Can I define a class with a single member in such a way that I can always upcast pointers to the member to instances of the class?

For example, given this class:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

class Packet {
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t k_size = 188;

    // Various functions omitted, they are all variations of this pattern
    bool is_flag(void) const {
        return (m_buffer[3] & 0x2) == 0x2;
    }

private:
    std::uint8_t m_buffer[k_size];
};
```

How can I support the following

```cpp
void some_func(std::uint8_t * buffer) {
    // Length checks, non-null checks omitted
    Packet * pkt = static_cast<Packet *>(buffer);
    if (pkt->is_flag()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The compiler will let me do `(Packet *)buffer` in place of `static_cast` -- is this well-formed? Are there scenarios where this introduces unexpected behavior? Is there any way to get `static_cast`?

## Avoiding the X->Y problem

My goal is to be able to use this class in two ways. In the case where I'm producing a stream of packets, I want to have instances of `Packet` which own their data. They exisit on the stack, and they go out of scope when I leave the function. Separately, the user may supply a pointer to a buffer containing multiple packets. I want to be able to perform operations on these packets, without copying them.

Comment: the title seems to contradict what you want to do. You seem to not want `Packet` to own the data, but rather be just a view on some data that comes from elsewhere

Comment: Fair, it was from an older draft of this question. Updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want the class to be like you want it to be. Such casting is juggling with scissors. It is possible to get it right somehow (I think), but there are just too many ways to get it wrong. And the safe alternative is simple: Do not make `Paket` own the data. Anyhow the data seems to be owned by someone else and you only have a pointer to the array managed by other code.

```
#include <cstdint>

class Packet {
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t k_size = 188;
    Packet(std::uint8_t* buffer) : m_buffer(buffer) {}
     
    // Various functions omitted, they are all variations of this pattern
    bool is_flag(void) const {
        return (m_buffer[3] & 0x2) == 0x2;
    }

private:
    std::uint8_t* m_buffer;
};
```

and then:

```
void some_func(std::uint8_t * buffer) {
    // Length checks, non-null checks omitted
    Packet pkt(buffer);
    if (pkt->is_flag()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

If you want the same class to either own the array or not own the array, you can make use of a `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter. I am not really suggesting to use this. The following is just to outline the idea. To make the class actually usable quite some effort has to be put in to implement proper rule of 5. And you need to be careful to consider all combinations, eg copying a owning instance to a non-owning one, or vice versa. If it is viable in your case I would rather consider to use polymorphism with one owning and one non-owning derived class. Anyhow, here we go...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <array>

struct array_mock {
    array_mock()  {std::cout << "construct";}
    ~array_mock() {std::cout << "destroyed";}
};

struct Packo {  

    Packo(array_mock* arr) : x{arr,my_deleter{false}} {} 
    Packo() : x{new array_mock(),my_deleter{true}} {}
    Packo(const Packo&) = delete;
    Packo(Packo&&) = delete;
    struct my_deleter {
        bool owning = true;
        void operator()(array_mock* ptr) { if (owning) delete ptr; }
    };    
    std::unique_ptr<array_mock,my_deleter> x;
};

int main() {
    Packo owning;
    Packo non_owning(owning.x.get());
}
```

In the [output](https://godbolt.org/z/Mbn3TfoM5):

```
constructdestroyed
```

We can see that only one `array_mock` is constructed and destroyed. The `non_owning` instance does not own the array, but uses the one owned by `owning`.

Comment: How does this handle the other mentioned use-case, though, where I want to have instances of Packet that do own their data? I'm worried with the above structure that it would be easy to accidentally create dangling pointers when passing packets to other parts of the application.

Comment: Explicitly, a function that returns a Packet by value, called from uncontrolled client code

Comment: @Carson hm, there is a way, but I am not sure if it is a good idea to do it. I will give it a try and update the answer

Comment: that is an interesting approach. Your suggestion to use polymorphism and have multiple owning and non-owning classes feels like a very good idea also. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this, although it requires to store extra data:

```
#include <cstdint>

class Packet {
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t k_size = 188;
    
    Packet() : m_buffer(real_buffer) {}
    Packet(std::uint8_t* buffer) : m_buffer(buffer) {}

    Packet(const Packet& other) {*this = other;}
    Packet(Packet&& other) {*this = other;}

    void operator=(const Packet& other)
    {
        if (other.m_buffer == other.real_buffer)
        {
            m_buffer = real_buffer;
            for (std::size_t i=0; i<k_size; i++)
                m_buffer[i] = other.m_buffer[i];
        }
        else
            m_buffer = other.m_buffer;
    }

    void operator=(Packet&& other)
    {
        if (other.m_buffer == other.real_buffer)
        {
            m_buffer = real_buffer;
            for (std::size_t i=0; i<k_size; i++)
                m_buffer[i] = other.m_buffer[i];
        }
        else
            m_buffer = other.m_buffer;
    }


    // Various functions omitted, they are all variations of this pattern
    bool is_flag(void) const {
        return (m_buffer[3] & 0x2) == 0x2;
    }

private:
    std::uint8_t* m_buffer;
    std::uint8_t real_buffer[k_size];
};

//and then:

void some_func(std::uint8_t * buffer) {
    // Length checks, non-null checks omitted
    Packet pkt(buffer);
    if (pkt.is_flag()) {
        // ...
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::uint8_t data[188];
    some_func(data);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a little scary because of the internal pointers. If I understand correctly, this class is not moveable. However, it is an interesting approach

Comment: I added a copy constructor. Moving the object seems to no be useful as real_buffer must be copied (it cannot be moved)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it’s specifically well-formed, but it is definitely not allowed by the c++ standard.
However, it does not lead to problems. (As long as you don’t make the class virtual in some way).
While some people advise not violating the standard in any way, I personally believe this case is fine and I do it a lot.